# SMTP prgram using JAVA Mail API

Tags: java, smtp

I am doing SMTP program usign java, I have a doubt. Can I use SMTP server IP instead of name like
can I use 64.233.183.109 instead of smtp.gmail.com for gmail smtp?

please tell me ..
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can, but should the IP change then it will break your script. Whats the problem with just using smtp.gmail.com? It will still show up as being sent from that hostname.

Comment: actually I am writeing this program for one of my client and they told me only server IP. so I have doubt

Comment: @atul make a property for the servername/ip address

Comment: Well, what happens when you use smtp.google.com is that it checks what the corresponding DNS entry for that domain is, then uses the IP from there on. So by using the IP directly all you're doing is missing out the DNS part (kind of). Like I said though, smtp.google.com will still show up as the sending host of the email.

Comment: K thnks, one more doubt I want to share that if I don't have internet connection.How could I ensure myself that it will work fine?

Comment: If you don't have an Internet connection then you can't send email via smtp so nothing to worry about!